# How to Bold our code lines in Jupyter lab

Tags: jupyter-lab

I downloard and start to work Jupyter lab software few days ago.I Can't find how to Bold code text.

As First step I go to Settings and go to Settings editor then I get pop up window.
in this window have font family,font size but I can't find font weight or any other thing to **bold** code text.
[Image in that pop up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNcDX.png)

Comment: Code is code, there is no way to apply formatting to parts of code. What exactly are you hoping to accomplish? A common way to highlight something in code is to add comments.

Comment: I would suggest you open an enhancement request in the [JupyterLab repository](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues). If there is no option to do something there will be until someone adds it.

Comment: @tripleee I understand the need for using bold font face when users have strained or impaired eyesight/vision; as far as I understand this question pertains to changing the style of code formatting so that it is easier to read in such circumstances, not highlighting a portion of it